# How to deploy a Dash application with waitress on Render.com

Tags: python, plotly-dash, render.com

I haven't used waitress before and now I want to use it for deploying a Dash app on Render.com.

My render.yalm file is:

```
services:
  # See https://render.com/docs/blueprint-spec for more info on render blueprints
  - type: web
    name: rehab_application_IOR
    env: python
    plan: free
    # A requirements.txt file must exist
    buildCommand: pip install -r requirements.txt
    # A src/app.py file must exist and contain `server=app.server`
    startCommand: waitress-serve src app:server 
    
    # startCommand: gunicorn --chdir src app:server 
    # entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app --timeout 600
    envVars:
      - key: PYTHON_VERSION
        value: 3.10.0
```

but it returns an error during deploying which says " Error: Specify one application only".
How can I solve it?